# How does a threading.Thread yield the rest of its quantum in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, yield

I've got a thread that's polling a piece of hardware.

```
while not hardware_is_ready():
    pass
process_data_from_hardware()
```

But there are other threads (and processes!) that might have things to do.  If so, I don't want to burn up cpu checking the hardware every other instruction.  It's been a while since I've dealt with threading, and when I did it wasn't Python, but I believe most threading libraries have a `yield` function or something that allows a thread to tell the scheduler "Give the other threads a chance."

```
while not hardware_is_ready():
    threading.yield()          # This function doesn't exist.
process_data_from_hardware()
```

But I can't find any reference to something like this in the threading documentation.  Python does have a `yield` statement, but I'm pretty sure that's something else entirely (to do with generators).

What's the correct thing to do here?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

`time.sleep(0)` is sufficient to yield control -- no need to use a positive epsilon.  Indeed, `time.sleep(0)` MEANS "yield to whatever other thread may be ready".

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?  I thought this might be true -- I've seen it in other languages -- but I couldn't find a mention of it in the Python docs.

Comment: for example, http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html "delayfunc will also be called with the argument 0 after each event is run to allow other threads an opportunity to run in multi-threaded applications." (delayfunc is usually time.sleep here).  I agree it would be nicer if it was documented more directly in module time;-)

Comment: Windows users: setting to 0 didn't work for me, time.sleep( 0.0001 ) did.

Comment: This is not working on Windows 7 with python 3.6.4 for me.

Answer (score 14):

Read up on the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL).

For example: http://jessenoller.com/2009/02/01/python-threads-and-the-global-interpreter-lock/

Also: http://www.pyzine.com/Issue001/Section_Articles/article_ThreadingGlobalInterpreter.html

Do this in your code if you must do **Busy Waiting** (e.g. polling a device).

```
time.sleep( 0.0001 )
```

This will yield to the thread scheduler.

Also, I collected some notes and references in http://homepage.mac.com/s_lott/iblog/architecture/C551260341/E20081031204203/index.html

Comment: I'm no expert, but I've read a bit on the GIL.  Could you give me a hint what in particular relates to this question?

I'll go with `time.sleep(epsilon)` for now, but it's kind of unsatisfying, isn't it?  There isn't any particular interval I want to sleep for.

Comment: Its the only solution if your hardware cannot send interrupts.

Comment: Without using `time.sleep()` how does Python perform pre-emptive yielding? On what conditions does a yield occur?

Comment: All three links seem broken.

Answer (score 6):

Why the yield in `time.sleep(0)` might not be enough:

I had a similar problem and ultimately `time.sleep(0)` did not work in all cases whereas `time.sleep(0.0001)` worked.
In my case I use the standard vanilla cpython - which can be found at python.org.
Looking at the implementation of the sleep function in the C code there is a tiny difference between a call of the `sleep(0)` and `sleep(something_other_than_null)`.

Looking at [pysleep in timemodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Modules/timemodule.c#L2052) you will see that in the first case

```cpp
if (ul_millis == 0 || !_PyOS_IsMainThread()) {
  Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
  Sleep(ul_millis);
  Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
  break;
}
```

is called. The "allow threads" releases the GIL, `Sleep(0)` in that case is equivalent to `std::this_thread::yield()`, after that the GIL is claimed again.
In the code that deals with a non-zero value, apart from the actual sleep/wait there is an additional call to [PyErr_CheckSignals](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_CheckSignals) - which as stated in its documentation "checks whether a signal has been sent to the processes and if so, invokes the corresponding signal handler". That would explain why in some cases when working with hardware a `time.sleep(0)` is not enough. So this might be a slip on cpython implementation side. And that is why `time.sleep(0.0001)` magically works.

Answer (score 4):

If you're doing this on *nix, you might find the [select](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html) library useful.  [Kamaela](http://www.kamaelia.org/Home) also has a few components you may find useful, but it may require a bit of a paradigm change.