# In there something similar to Java's Thread.yield() in Python? Does that even make sense?

Tags: python, multithreading, sleep, yield

I want to tell my Python threads to yield, and so avoid hogging the CPU unnecessarily. In Java, you could do that using the `Thread.yield()` function. I don't think there is something similar in Python, so I have been using `time.sleep(t)` where `t = 0.00001`. For `t=0` there seems to be no effect.

I think that maybe there is something I am not understanding correctly about Python's threading model, and hence the reason for the missing `thread.yield()`. Can someone clarify this to me? Thanks!

PS: This is what the documentation for Java's `Thread.yield()` says:

> Causes the currently executing thread
>   object to temporarily pause and allow
>   other threads to execute.

Comment: when t=0, it yields for any other thread that is ready

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I tried that but doesn't seem to work. Maybe I am measuring incorrectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The interpreter will switch from one thread to another periodically anyway without your intervention - you don't need to tell the system not to 'hog' a thread.

However, under normal circumstances, only one Python thread is executing at any one time. (Exceptions tend to revolve around times when threads are waiting on input from external devices such as the hard disk or the network.) This is due to the [Global Interpreter Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock). This does mean however that you probably aren't getting as much benefit from threads in Python as you would in Java or many other languages. Getting around this problem is not necessarily trivial, although moving to [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) instead of multithreading is one good approach, if possible.

However, what you want to do seems flawed in some sense - if you have 2 threads and they both have work to do, you shouldn't have to write application-side code to switch between them. That's the job of the operating system or the virtual machine. If you find yourself telling one thread to 'do less' because you want to favour another thread in terms of processor time, then rather than adding arbitrary yielding or sleeping, you should probably be setting thread priorities instead. (Although again, this may not have much meaning in Python given the presence of the Global Interpreter Lock.)

Comment: What happens when a thread is not yielding, is that it starts to starve the other threads. Java and C (pthreads) have yielding functions to tell the scheduler that the thread is "free". The answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787803/how-does-a-threading-thread-yield-the-rest-of-its-quantum-in-python/787810#787810 seems to give some further insight, but it seems that I can not get around it.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how threads work on most systems. The system will switch between threads automatically on a very regular basis so all threads get to run. (This is called 'pre-emption' or 'preemptive multitasking'.) You don't need to manually switch between them on Java or Python. Methods such as yield() on such systems are a minor optimisation, not a requirement.

Comment: Yielding might be useful if you're sitting tight on a loop and doing busy wait (e.g. when polling), as you constantly hint to the scheduler that you're not actually doing any work. Thread priorities do not work here as the polling thread doesn't have lower priority, but rather just has "less work to do" when busy waiting. Note that ideally you'd prefer to not schedule the polling thread at all until the event of interest actually happens, but if you're resorting to polling then it probably means you cannot do that anyway.

Comment: The GIL issue in Python is that a thread that's sitting on a loop doing busy waiting will preclude other threads from doing useful work (until it's preempted). Yielding is therefore a nice optimization in this case.

Comment: No, no. I know about pre-emption. The `yield` I am referring to (in the case of Java or pthreads) is simply advising the scheduler. It is a way to suggest a pre-emption point. As you say it is an optimization. I need to go and read more about the GIL. Thanks.

Comment: If your thread is wasting time doing something you don't need to do all that often, it would be better to find some way to have the system wake up your thread when there is work to do, instead of adding tiny sleeps or yields which are a hack at best. Python's threading library provides condition variables, for example.

Comment: Thanks @Kylotan, the `Condition` variables is what I was looking for. And you are right, in this case tiny sleeps or waits are a hack, and hence my original question.

Comment: Also, it was very useful to read the implementation of `Queue` and `collections.deque`.

Answer (score 12):

Dup of: [How does a threading.Thread yield the rest of its quantum in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787803/how-does-a-threading-thread-yield-the-rest-of-its-quantum-in-python).

```
time.sleep(0)
```

Comment: My problem is that `time.sleep(0)` does not seem to have any effect. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: hrms, odd, if it doesn't work something else weird must be happening. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thread.yield() is missing from python because perhaps it has been forgotten, or the designer thought that all synchronization and interprocess communication issues are solvable without Thread.yield().

I'd use Thread.yield() for the following issue:

E.g. there is a job queue and there are 2 worker threads which can fetch entries from the job queue and place entries into the job queue.
One way to solve it is to use the threading.Condition class.
When worker 'B' wants to fetch a queue entry, but the queue is empty, it goes to wait state (Condition.wait()). When worker 'A' places entry into the queue, it wakes up worker 'B' (Condition.notify()). At this point yielding is essential, because if worker 'A' doesn't yield here, worker 'A' can fetch the task before the woken up worker 'B' which causes race condition issue.

I wonder how it is solvable without Thread.yield().

Comment: Didn't OP ask for why `thread.yield()` is missing in python? I don't think that an explanation of `thread.yield()` suits the question.

Comment: Sure. But many people are arguing about that yield is not needed, because  of the pre-emption. I think thread.yield() is missing, because it has been simply forgotten.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer to give a possible answer for the "why is it missing?" question.

Comment: Waiting on the condition causes the context switch you need in your example, it "yields" because this thread blocks on the condition and has no choice other than switching to another runnable thread.