# Best way to switch threads in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm writing unit tests for a Python multithreaded program. Unit testing multithreaded programs is always difficult, but I have it working pretty well. One issue I have is that since the Python threads take turns, instead of running in parellel or time sliced, I often find myself writing tests like:

```
# Act
object_being_tested.do_function_that_triggers_other_thread_to_run()
time.sleep(0.1)  # Let the worker thread run

# Verify    
self.assertEqual(value_that_worker_thread_should_have_set, object_being_tested.get_value())

# Cleanup
object_being_tested.worker_thread.join()
```

This works pretty well but the 'time.sleep(0.1)' seems awkward to me. Is there a clean way in python to indicate that I don't want to sleep, I just want to switch away from the current thread and let the other thread run? Or is a short sleep the best way?

Comment: "Unit testing multithreaded programs is always difficult" yup. to me your options are: 1. set a flag variable that the computation is done and poll until that variable is changed before calling `get_value` 2. actually just `join` the thread. 3. create a separate mutex (similar to 1) that you can `acquire`. 4. Keep what you've got if it works...

Comment: Does this answer the question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908206/in-there-something-similar-to-javas-thread-yield-in-python-does-that-even-ma