# Simple, non-blocking background calls

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyside

I'm writing an PySide application that communicates with hardware over a serial connection.

I have a button to start the device command and a label to show the result to the user.
Now some devices take a long time (multiple seconds) to answer a request, which freezes the GUI. I am searching for a simple mechanism to run the call in a background thread or similar.

I created a short example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
import sys
import time
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui


class Device(QtCore.QObject):

    def request(self, cmd):
        time.sleep(3)
        return 'Result for {}'.format(cmd)


class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, device, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.device = device

        self.layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel('--')
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Go')
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.go)

    def go(self):
        self.button.setEnabled(False)

        # the next line should be called in the
        # background and not freeze the gui
        result = self.device.request('command')

        self.label.setText(result)
        self.button.setEnabled(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dev = Device()
    win = Dialog(device=dev)
    win.show()
    win.raise_()
    app.exec_()
```

What I wish to have is some kind of function like:

```
result = nonblocking(self.device.request, 'command')
```

Exceptions should be raised as if I called the function directly.

Any ideas or recommendations?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265812/pyside-pyqt-starting-a-cpu-intensive-thread-hangs-the-whole-application, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879971/example-of-the-right-way-to-use-qthread-in-pyqt, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783194/background-thread-with-qthread-in-pyqt or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752154/pyqt-connecting-a-signal-to-a-slot-to-start-a-background-operation

Answer (score 2):

Threading is the best way to do that. Python threads are really easy to use too. Qt threads don't work the same way as python threads. http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

I just use python threads. Also if you are using a serial port connection you may want to split the data off into a queue which is thread safe.

```
import time
import threading
import queue
import serial

def read_serial(serial, storage):
    while True:
        value = serial.readline()
        storage.put(value) # or just process the data

ser = serial.SerailPort("Com1", 9600)
stor = queue.Queue()
th = threading.Thread(target=read_serial, args=(ser, stor))
th.start()
for _ in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)
th.join(0)
ser.close()
# Read queue
```

The other thing you can do is use multiple inheritance for the serial port and the QObject. This allows you to use Qt signals. Below is a very rough example.

```
class SerialThread(object):
    def __init__(self, port=None, baud=9600):
        super().__init__()

        self.state = threading.Condition() # Notify threading changes safely
        self.alive = threading.Event() # helps with locking

        self.data = queue.Queue()
        self.serial = serial.Serial()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self._run)

        if port is not None:
            self.connect(port, baud)
    # end Constructor

    def connect(self, port, baud):
        self.serial.setPort(port)
        self.serial.setBaudrate(baud)
        self.serial.open()

        with self.state:
            self.alive.set()
        self.thread.start()
    # end connect

    def _run(self):
        while True:
            with self.state:
                if not self.alive.is_set():
                    return

            self.read()
    # end _run

    def read(self):
        serstring = bytes("", "ascii")
        try:
            serstring = self.serial.readline()
        except:
            pass
        else:
            self.process_read(serstring)
        return serstring # if called directly
    # end read

    def process_read(self, serstring):
        if self.queue.full():
            self.queue.get(0) # remove the first item to free up space
        self.queue.put(serstring)
    # end process_read

    def disconnect(self):
        with self.state:
            self.alive.clear()
            self.state.notify()
        self.thread.join(0) # Close the thread
        self.serial.close() # Close the serial port
    # end disconnect
# end class SerialThread

class SerialPort(SerialThread, QtCore.QObject):
    data_updated = QtCore.Signal()

    def process_read(self, serstring):
        super().process_read(serstring)
        self.data_updated.emit()
    # end process_read
# end class SerialPort


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ser = SerialPort()
    ser.connect("COM1", 9600)
    # Do something / wait / handle data
    ser.disconnect()
    ser.queue.get() # Handle data
```

As always make sure you properly close and disconnect everything when you exit. Also note that a thread can only be run once, so you may want to look at a pausable thread example [How to start and stop thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729498/how-to-start-and-stop-thread).
You can also just emit the data through a Qt Signal instead of using a queue to store the data.

Comment: A bit 'rough' indeed, but I eventually got it to work on Python2.7 & PySide.

Answer (score 1):

> What I wish to have is some kind of function like:
>
> ```
>     result = nonblocking(self.device.request, 'command')
> ```

What you are asking for here is effectively impossible. You cannot have a non-blocking call return a result immediately! That, by definition, would be a blocking call.

A non-blocking call would look something like:

```
self.thread = inthread(self.device.request, 'command', callback)
```

Where `self.device.request` runs the `callback` function/method at the completion of the serial request. However, naively calling `callback()` from within the thread will make the callback run in the thread, which is very very bad if you were to make calls to the Qt GUI from the `callback` method (Qt GUI methods are not thread safe). As such, you need a way of running the callback in the MainThread.

I've had a similar need for such functions, and have created (with a colleague) a library (called [qtutils](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/qtutils/)) which has some nice wrapper functions in it (including an implementation of `inthread`). It works by posting an event to the MainThread using `QApplication.postEvent()`. The event contains reference to a function to be run, and the event handler (which resides in the main thread) executes that function. So your `request` method would then look like:

```
def request(self, cmd, callback):
    time.sleep(3)
    inmain(callback, 'Result for {}'.format(cmd))
```

where `inmain()` makes posts an event to the main thread and runs `callback(data)`.

Documentation for this library can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/philipstarkey/qtutils/wiki/invoke_in_main), or alternatively, you can role your own based on the outline above. If you choose to use my library, it can be installed via pip or easy_install.

Note: One caveat with this method is that `QApplication.postEvent()` [leaks memory in PySide](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/PYSIDE-205). That's why I now use PyQt!

Comment: PySide does not seem to be "quite error free". And they also do not support Qt5.