# how real programmer do server loop?

Tags: python, multithreading

everytime when running this program, I hear my cpu fan is boosting. I suspected the busy waiting while loops in the code is the cause. I wonder how a real programmer will do to optimize this?

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import threading
class PThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        #view leave will set this event
        self.event = threading.Event()
    def run(self):
        while 1:
            if not self.event.is_set():
               print 'run'
            else:
               break



def server_control(queue):
    while True:
        try:
            event = queue.get(False)
        except:
            event = None
        if event == 'DETECTED':
            print 'DETECTED'
            t = PThread()
            t.start()
        elif event == 'LEAVE':
            print 'Viewer_left'
            t.event.set()
            t.join()
        elif event == 'QUIT':
                break
q=Queue()
p = Process(target=server_control, args=(q,))
p.start()
p.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiprocessing module has a clone of threading's event object

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Event
```

Instead of use a Queue. You should declare event of interest in your main and pass them to other process
In your case:

```
detected = Event()
leave = Event()
exit = Event()

Process(target=server_control, args=(detected, leave, exit))
```

and finally check if the event is fired or wait in your loop

Answer (score 5):

If a thread needs to wait for an event, it should sleep until the event occurs, rather than busy-waiting.  Your event object has a `wait()` method that can be used to accomplish that.  Call it, and it won't return until some other thread has called `set()` on the event (or the timeout elapses, if you specify one).  In the meantime, the thread uses no CPU.

Answer (score 0):

You might make the loop a bit less tight by adding a `time.sleep(0)` in the loop to pass the remainder of the quantum to another thread.

See also: [How does a threading.Thread yield the rest of its quantum in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787803/how-does-a-threading-thread-yield-the-rest-of-its-quantum-in-python)